# How to run concordion tests in Play?

Tags: java, sbt, playframework-2.2, concordion

I'm trying to run concordion test in my Play application 2.2.1 in Java.

It works when I run the test from my IDE but not from the play or sbt console: the html file is not moved to `target` folder.

In `{project_dir}\target\scala-2.10\test-classes\specs\example`, there is only `HelloWorldFixture.class`, and no HTML file, and thus the concordion test fails.

[image: tree]

So far I have tried to follow the article [How to integrate Concordion in Play Framework and write acceptance tests in natural language](http://www.poornerd.com/2013/07/05/how-to-integrate-concordion-in-play-framework-and-write-acceptance-tests-in-natural-language/), but it is made for the 2.0 version not the 2.2.1 and the `scala.build` file has disappeared.

I've tried to put the line `unmanagedClasspath in Test <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "test") }` in `build.sbt` and in `project/plugins.sbt`.

I've also tried to use several other versions of the line that I could find in [Classpaths, sources, and resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html).
 Nothing has worked.

Comment: Right - when I was doing it, it did not work when running "test-only" (as in the [link](http://www.poornerd.com/2013/07/05/how-to-integrate-concordion-in-play-framework-and-write-acceptance-tests-in-natural-language/) article you mentioned).  I am pretty sure it was a bug in Play - maybe that is what you are encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the test resources (HTML files) moved to `target` directory follow the default project structure as described in [Source code](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Directories.html#source-code) or [Testing](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing), i.e. `src/test/resources` that contains *files to include in test jar here*.

Comment: Play doesn't use this structure, I found how to do it but I'm not sure how I've done it. So i'm investigating and I will post the answer as soon as I got it.